# SQL CLR UDF Returning Type Name ()

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sqlclr

I am using a Visual Studio 2012 Database project with a CLR UDF (below).  For some reason, after deploying it to the database, I call the function and I get the type name returned instead of the expected result.

```
public partial class UserDefinedFunctions
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction]
    public static SqlChars FlattenText(SqlChars text)
    {
        return new SqlChars(Regex.Replace(text.ToString(), @"\s+", " ", RegexOptions.Multiline));
    }
}
```

When I call it like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 dbo.FlattenText(MyColumn) AS MyResult FROM MyTable
```

Here is what I get returned:

```
System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlChars
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SqlChars` inherits `.ToString()` from `Object` which simply returns the type name.  Use `text.ToSqlString().ToString()` instead.

Comment: That worked.  I didn't think to look at the members of that type.  Thank you.